# Sequence of jointly Gaussian random variables of unit variance converging to zero

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Does there exist a sequence of jointly normal random variables $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with
$$\mathbb{E} X_n = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{E} X_n^2 = 1$$
for all $n \ge 1$, for which $X_n \to 0$ almost surely?

Clearly if all the $X_n$ are independent this does not hold, but if for example $X_1 = X_2 = \dots$, then this fails only slightly: There does not exist any deterministic constant $C > 0$ such that almost surely $|X_k| < C$ for large enough $k$.

Comment: Convergence almost surely implies convergence in distribution, so....

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Can you elaborate? From distributional convergence it does not follow that variances converge, for example.

Comment: All of your random variables are standard normal, with variance equal 1.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Sorry. I think I see what you are after now. The distributional limit would have to be normal also. If you post some sort of an answer, I can accept that and this question can be forgotten.

Comment: Sorry, I had to run off and give a calculus exam. I have now posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence in distribution gives 
$${\cal N}(0,1),\, {\cal N}(0,1),\, {\cal N}(0,1),\, {\cal N}(0,1),\cdots\Longrightarrow  {\cal L}(X),$$
where ${\cal L}(X)$ is the distribution of $X$. The only possible limit
 point of a constant sequence is the constant itself, so ${\cal L}(X)={\cal N}(0,1).$